# Is WWE on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some of the World Wrestling Entertainment characters (such as The Undertaker and Kane) are clearly supernatural. There are probably more if we dig around enough into the earlier days of the WWF (World Wrestling Federation).

They have enough viewers that there probably are people who are well versed in their lore. Is the WWE on topic here?

Comment: Could you expand those acronyms? Presumably you aren't talking about World Wrestling Entertainment or the World Wildlife Fund.

Comment: On the contrary, Precisely what i am talking about

Comment: Admittedly I don't watch sports, but how could a wrestling show possibly be sci-fi or fantasy? And why is a wildlife foundation included in the same question?

Comment: The show's storylines are the supernatural part

Comment: Wwe used to be called wwf until they got too big and the wildlife foundation found it worth their time to sue them to change their name

Comment: Also, wildlife can be supernatural at times

Comment: @user13267 - Well, no. WWF (the wrestling people) violated the agreement they signed in good faith with WWF (the panda people), then tried to sue in order to get exclusive use of a trademark that the panda people had been using for nearly a century;  https://babyfacevheel.substack.com/p/heres-the-real-story-of-how-the-wwf

Comment: Possibly even more so, promotions like Chikara (may it rest in peace) or Kaiju Big Battel that are more explicitly fantasy/sci-fi in their trappings.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. A spokesman for WWF [admitted under oath](https://www.nytimes.com/1989/02/10/nyregion/now-it-can-be-told-those-pro-wrestlers-are-just-having-fun.html) that the 'sport' was nothing of the sort. It was merely an entertainment.

> The World Wrestling Federation asks in the legislation that
> professional wrestling be defined as *"an activity in which
> participants struggle hand-in-hand primarily for the purpose of
> providing entertainment to spectators rather than conducting a bona
> fide athletic contest."*

As such, the [plotlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayfabe) and "[gimmicks](https://second.wiki/wiki/won_best_gimmick)" used in the ring can be considered a form of theatre and would be as much on-topic here as questions about the Harry Potter stage show.

Comment: Would this apply to all WWE actors or to those only demonstrating supernatural abilities?

Comment: @Skooba - Only the supernatural ones, I'd say. Their powers are ill-defined and inconsistently presented, basically as the plot requires.